# get the content when the div does not have the id of the div ... only has the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Good afternoon. I have a table listing days. These days are within a `<div>`, but I do not have an ID for the `<div>`. I tried to get the contents of the `<div>` but it still fails, as it does when I try to get the value.

This is an example of the `<div>` I'm trying to get the class of.

```
<div class="fc-day-number">6</div>`
```

I'm trying to get this value with the Seguito function but am not getting the value of the content div ..

```
$(".fc-widget-content").click(function () {
var diaSelecionado = $('.fc-day-number').val();
        alert(diaSelecionado);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `val()`, use `.html()` to return the element's `innerHTML` property:

```
$(".fc-widget-content").click(function () {
var diaSelecionado = $('.fc-day-number').html();
        alert(diaSelecionado);
    });
});
```

Comment: the answers were very helpful ...  $(".fc-widget-content").click(function () {
var diaSelecionado = $('.fc-day-number').html();
        alert(diaSelecionado);
    });
});

Answer (score 3):

[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is used to get the value of form elements, you probably want [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$(".fc-widget-content").click(function () {
    var diaSelecionado = $('.fc-day-number').html();
    alert(diaSelecionado);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery documentation:

The **.val()** method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

In an HTML document, **.html()** can be used to get the contents of any element.

You will want to change the `$('.fc-day-number').val();` to `$('.fc-day-number').html()`;